# Passing back data after onResponse with volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I need to get some data that is returned from the api call (where the 'Get something and set.. comment is) to be returned by the api_call function. How do I do this, since everything I've tried doesn't seem to allow me to move data from inside the 'onResponse' to be returned from the 'api_call'

```
public void api_call(String Location){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    String api_key = "xxxxxx";
    String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org./data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + api_key + "&units=metric";
    String Number;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response){
            //Get something and set it to the number variable
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
            ;
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    return Number
}
```

Comment: Your code does not even compile as a void function cannot return a value.

Comment: The void function has ended long before onResponse is triggered or the request has started. Its only in the queue then.

Comment: Implementing a callback will work for you in this case above

Comment: onResponse() is the callback.

Answer (score 1):

set first parameter in `new StringRequest()` your request method.
example `Request.Method.GET`

And initialize a interface for return your string

```
public interface NumberCallback{
    void onSuccess(Int number);

    void onError(VolleyError error);
}
```

And You can't have a void function with return value.so delete return and replace this code into onResponse() method

```
NumberCallback.onSuccess(number);
```

then into Destination receive callback. ask if you don't how receive callback.